# Random generation of different variables in the same data frame

Tags: r, apply, simulation, lapply

Lets say i have following two sets.

```
set1=sample(c("White","Black"),
       20,prob = c(0.6,0.4),replace = TRUE)
set2=sample(c("yes","no"),
            20,prob = c(0.48,0.32),replace = TRUE)
```

from this **i need to generate 20 (random)times where each replication contain one column from each set which is randomly generated.**.That is for example , the "set 1" in the replication 2 should not be identical to the "set 1" in the replication 1.

In other words, each replication should be randomly generated.

Can anyone help me to do that ?

I know how to generate 20 replications separately for each set as follows,

```
replicate(n=20,set1)
replicate(n=20,set2)
```

But here each variable randomly generated 20 times separately   . What i need is  something like replication(randomly generation) of each variable simultaneously.

May be i have to use lapply so that i should create 20 lists where each list has 2 columns based on set 1 and set 2 . but i dont have a clue how to do it.

Comment: Can you add your desired output? I'm struggling to understand exactly what you're after

Comment: @RAB so my output should be like a list (random). each list should contain 2 columns . one is "set1" and other is "set2" .

Comment: I meant create an artificial output that you want to see and add that to the question by editing the questions itself. Do lists even have columns? Are you thinking about data.frames?

Answer (score 2):

We can define a function which generates the dataframe randomly and call it 20 times using `replicate` to get list of 20 dataframes.

```
my_func <- function(set1, set2) {
    data.frame(set1 = sample(set1), set2 = sample(set2))
}

replicate(20, my_func(set1, set2), simplify = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi.  This is not what i want. here a copy of "df" will repeat 20 times. instead of generating 20 different lists. I need random 20 lists which has 2 columns 1 from set 1 and other from set 2

Comment: @student_R123 This does actually give you a list of length 20 and every element has two columns. If you do `lst <- replicate(20, df, simplify = FALSE)` and then `length(lst)` it will return 20. If this is not your expected output, can you update your post with it?

Comment: The layout of the output is the one i want. But in each iteration (replication) each variable should be randomly generated. I edited the question. Thank you